# Applying Extension method to generic class with generic type

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, static-typing

I was working with the generic class in vb.net.
And it seems extension method cannot be applied to generic class without specifying the type.

I have this generic class

```
Public Class MyGeneric(Of T)
    'Methods and properties go here 
    '
    '
End Class
```

This is Ok

```
<Extension()> _
Public Sub DoSomething(ByVal myGenericDoubleObj As MyGen(Of Double))

End Sub
```

This is NOT Ok(IDE gives me error T as not defined.)

```
<Extension()> _
Public Sub DoSomethingGeneric(ByVal myGenericObj As MyGen(Of T))

End Sub
```

Is this something to do with the static checking of the .Net.
Saying me "Something which may you try with doing with Type T is may not compatible and I will not allow you to do it."

P.S. All the this pain I have taken as Generic Class comes from another library, And used at many different places. I am little wary of inheriting and adding this method in my inherited generic class.

Comment: +1 for exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you make your extension method a generic method it should work

i.e DoSomething **(Of T)** () instread of just DoSomething()

```
<Extension()> _
Public Sub DoSomething(Of T)(ByVal myGenericObj As MyGeneric(Of T))
End Sub
```

Hope this helps

Comment: C# version: public static void DoSomething<T>(this MyGeneric<T> myGenericObj)