# Extension class for List(of AnyType) not working

Tags: .net, vb.net, list

I want to create a extension class for the List type so users can do

```
ListObject.AddDistinct("value")
```

I want the method to work with all types of list so:

```
List(Of Integer)
List(Of String)
```

etc etc. My extensions is

```
Module ListsExtensions
<Extension()>
Public Sub AddDistinct(ByRef ls As List(Of Type), ByVal obj As Type)
    If Not ls.Contains(obj) Then ls.Add(obj)
End Sub
End Module
```

I've it defined as Type and also tried object but neither are accessible when I have a list of strings.

If I set it to be string it then appears..But I want something that is more generic and will work with all lists. How do I need to define it?

Comment: This looks like it has been asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349064/applying-extension-method-to-generic-class-with-generic-type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List(Of AnyType)` is called a generic class. It's how the class works with any type yet remains strongly-typed rather than using `Object`.

For your extension method to be generic, you need to declare the generic type like so (I'm using `T` instead of `Type` here to follow .NET naming conventions):

```
<Extension()>
Public Sub AddDistinct(Of T)(ByRef ls As List(Of T), ByVal obj As T)
    If Not ls.Contains(obj) Then ls.Add(obj)
End Sub
```